# How do I rearrange the follow up prompts in the QnA Maker without editing the prompt?

Tags: azure-qna-maker

I would like to organize my follow-up prompts to be in a specific order but when I edit them they move around and not in the order.

I've tried clicking and dragging the prompts but that does not move the prompts

I would like to arrange the prompts in a specific order

Answer (score 0):

There is an open issue for this. Please see here:
https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-tools/issues/1281